# calling function inside render() not rendering content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to create this simple search filter app with react  where if the user type something in the search bar or check on the checkbox the result will appear on the screen according to the search input, but for now the renderResult is not returning my list of results. i got no error in the console, and i got the correct result when i console log the result inside the renderResult function. but the result is not rendering on screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes from 'react-multiselect-checkboxes';

class App extends Component {

state = { 
  name: '',
  style: [],
  furnitures: null 
};

stylesOption = [
  { value: 'classic', label: 'Classic' },
  { value: 'midcentury', label: 'Midcentury' },
  { value: 'scandinavian', label: 'Scandinavian' },
  { value: 'modern', label: 'Modern' },
  { value: 'contemporary', label: 'Contemporary'}
]

componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchFurnitures();
} 

fetchFurnitures = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('some-url')

  this.setState({ furnitures: response.data.products });

}


onInputChange = e => {
  this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  this.filterInput(e.target.value)
}

onFurnitureStyleChange = e => {
  this.setState({style: e})
  this.filterByStyle(e)
}

filterInput(searchTerm){
  let result = this.state.furnitures.filter (({ name }) => {
    return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  })
}

filterByStyle(searchTerm){

  let searchByStyle = searchTerm;
  let result = this.state.furnitures.filter(({ furniture_style }) =>
  searchByStyle.every(s => furniture_style.includes(s.label)));

  return this.renderResult(result)

}

renderResult = result => {
  if(result){
    return result.map((res) => {        
      return (
        <div>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Card>
                <CardContent>
                   <h1>{res.name}</h1>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      )
    })
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        id="standard-uncontrolled"
        placeholder="Search Furniture"
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        margin="normal"
      />
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
            <ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes  onChange={this.onFurnitureStyleChange} options={this.stylesOption} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      {this.renderResult()}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `renderResult` definition ,it need a param `result`.

But in render,you calling `{this.renderResult()}` without `result` data.

```
{this.renderResult()} //no param/result passed
```

So,its returning null.

Comment: after reading your comment, i just realized that i don't need to call renderResult() inside the render because its called only onchange when user input something, i tried deleting the function call inside render but i got same result. sorry i might have worded the title wrong here

Comment: But renderResult return html to display on UI.So,u need to call anyway inside render using result data

Comment: you're right, i need to refactor the code a little. thanks